# ClickOnce app installation and usage error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I wrote ClickOnce application (WpfApplication) using Visual Studio 2012.
When I publish it (to removeable) and install on my computer it's working fine.
But when I try it on other computer, I get the following error:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.17929
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///D:/user/Downloads/WpfApplication.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : WpfApplication.application, Version=1.0.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7100e24044f1f15, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of he errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of D:\user\Downloads\WpfApplication.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [04/10/2014 10:39:05] : Activation of D:\user\Downloads\WpfApplication.application has started.
    * [04/10/2014 10:39:05] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [04/10/2014 10:39:05] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [04/10/2014 10:39:05] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (Zone)
        - Deployment and application do not have matching security zones.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Before publishing, I made sure that my project is:

- a full trust application.
- aviliable offline as well
- signed my app using test certification

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to at least sign your application by test certification.
2. If any antivirus program is installed, disable it
3. If you are directly    install from an url, use Internet Explorer